# Dynamicly update php variable on change of multiple input fields without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I'm not familiar with js and tried the example shown here ([jQuery - update variable when input values changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118114/jquery-update-variable-when-input-values-changed)) but it's not working for me.

What I need is the following: I have a variable, that has to show the total qty entered in input fields. I.e on every input field change I have to sum the entered qty. My code is as follow:

```
<?PHP
$counter = 0;
?>

<div class="total">
    TotalPcs:
    <span class="running_total">
        <?= $counter ?> <!-- this is the var showing the total qty -->
    </span>
</div>
<?php
<form method="post">
    foreach ($object->getExternalProducts($orderlang) as $result) {
        print '<tr>';
        print '<td>' . $result->label . '</td>';
        print '<td><input type="number" class="qty_field" name="productid_' .$result->rowid . '" value="" /></td>';
        print '<tr>';
    }
</form>
?>
```

As you can see, the name of the field is populated based on SQL query and appends the ID of each product after `productid_` so I cannot use the name field. I can strip the 'productid_' but it's obvious that it is easier to use 'class' or 'id' of the field.

And the JS file:

```
$('body').on('keyup', '.qty_field', function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.qty_field').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });

    $('.running_total').html(sum);
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That PHP code inside your `<form>` won't run, missing `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: @brombeer It is there, just forgot to write it. I've updated the code.

Comment: Actually @brombeer I think its the `<form method="post">` that wont compile now, but 6 of one and half a dozen of the other :)

Comment: @milenmk Placed them at the wrong position ... Don't _write_ stuff here but copy/paste your original code. (There might be a typo in your original code that you miss when writing here)

Comment: "Not working" is not a proper problem description. Please explain how _exactly_ this is "not working". Do you get any JS errors in the console? Have you verified your event handler function fires at all?

Comment: @brombeer I've copied the code from the mentioned topic and amended it as written here. So, the code I am trying to use is as written above. problem is that the total field does not get updated, so I guess I have a mistake, but as I said I am not familiar with js and can't figure it out. What I need is to update the total value after input field change without reloading the page.

Comment: That's invalid code as of now. As others mentioned you need to be a bit more specific about what doesn't work. Nothing in your browser's DevConsole? Is jquery loaded? Is the wrong field updated? Is the sum incorrect?